# Printer race condition?

Tags: java, printing

So I have some code that I'm modifying. Without going into huge details about what it is actually doing, it can be summarized by creating a file and then sending it to a printer. Essentially the following:

```
File file = new File("/tmp/12345.pdf");
//Lots of magical code that creates/writes to said file
...
...
...
//sendToPrinter essentially builds up a print command to send to /usr/bin/lp and then executes it.
sendToPrinter(printer, details, file);

file.delete();// This is the line I'm curious about.
```

My question is that the call to lp is made before we get to file.delete(). However, does this run the risk of creating a race condition where I actually end up deleting the file before the printer is ready?

From preliminary testing, I have yet to see a problem, but something about this bothers me. Have I created the risk of a race condition by doing this?

Edit: Clarification based upon comments. Yes, I'm utilizing lp and sendToPrinter does appear to be waiting for a return code. The code is not asynchronous.

Comment: Assuming you mean you execute the external `/usr/bin/lp` (or similar)  command , it would depend on whether sendToPrinter() waits until the lp command is finished or not

Comment: Is your program synchronous or asynchronous? are you running on more than one thread?

Comment: What's the content of `sendToPrinter(...)`? If it asynchronous (which I doubt it) then "yes", you might have a race condition; otherwise (more likely) not.

Comment: you can delete a file while it is being opened by another process...

Comment: I'm more curious what happens if lp command returns 0 and CUPS is still using the file for something when I try to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

From doc

> The join method allows one thread to wait for the completion of
>   another. If t is a Thread object whose thread is currently executing,
>
> t.join(); causes the current thread to pause execution until t's
>   thread terminates.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()